# Get the buttons on a Jquery UI Dialog and then Add a Button to It with an ID Attriubute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I can add a button to the dialog with the following code:

```
var buttonName = "test";
var func = new function(){alert("")};

var buttons = $('#SomeID').dialog('option', 'buttons');
buttons[buttonName] = func;
$('#SomeID').dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
```

But I want my button to also have an ID, how do I add a button with an ID attribute???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me. You use the buttons array and use the `push` function to add another element to it. Now you'll only have to figure out how to attach the functionality to it.

```
var buttons = $('#content').dialog('option', 'buttons');
buttons.push({text: buttonName, id: 'test', click: function() { alert('Works'); }});
$('#content').dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
```

Comment: Hmm this is really weird when I use .push() it doesn't push anything onto the array.... I have now got it working but instead of push I use buttons[buttons.length + 1] = {text: buttonName, id: 'test', click: function() { alert('Works'); }

Comment: I believe buttons isn't an array but an object which explains why push doesn't work but setting an object with key of buttons.length+1 works if you set the text and other stuff in the object you set it as.